# Why must my edit to my own question be peer reviewed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[Why can't I get a decent white background with product photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38343/why-cant-i-get-a-decent-white-background-with-product-photgraphy/38347#38347)

I edited my answer to this question and I get a message saying the edit will only appear to me until it has been peer reviewed.

Comment: The edit history shows the addition of the picture was done by an anonymous user. There may be a bug there, but are you sure you were logged in when you made the edit. Different browser perhaps?

Comment: Same browser. When I opened a new tab to get to meta I saw that it asked me to log in but then recognized me before I pressed any keys to do so. I guess it was a bug to do with my log in status. I went back to the same tab I submitted the edit on and reviewed and approved my own edit that was showing as submitted by anonymous! LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your account was logged out while editing (I can't ascertain why by looking at the logs). The system then accepted your edit as anonymous, which is why you had to approve it after signing in again.